# Can I Delete EntityFramework.dll from a standard MVC 3 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

When creating a standard MVC 3 project there is an EntityFramework.dll and .xml file in the Bin folder and a reference to the dll in the solution.

I'm not going to be using Entity Framework at all. Can the reference and DLL/XML files be removed from the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the EntityFramework dll is used in the standard out of the box implementation of asp membership so if this is something that you are going to implement yourself using some other ORM or data access then I can see no reason why you would need to keep the reference.

Comment: We will be using an API for all data. No database or EF will be used from MVC at all. Wasn't sure if it was required for some part of MVC that i've not came across as i'm new to MVC.

Comment: Creating a new internet application project in MVC will basically create a default implementation of an ASP.NET Membership provider, if you create a new project and run it you will see that logging in, registering, changing passwords etc all work right out of the box. Entity Framework is used to save and retreive the user related records which is why the EntityFramework dll is included... if you are going to not use this standard implementation then removing the Entity Framework will not be an issue for you.